# load lot of images into titanium image view

Tags: android, memory-management, titanium, appcelerator

I'm loading a lot of images into a image views in titanium. the problem is that in android I get memory problems. this is my function to put the image into the image view. In this function i'm resizing the image.

```
exports.SetImg = function(img, hightFactor, widthFactor, viewObj, deviceWidth, deviceHeight) {


    if (img != null && img != "") {
        var IMGhight = 0,
            IMGwidth = 0,
            height = 0,
            width = 0;

        var imgTemp = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image : img
        });
        if (imgTemp != null) {

            if (imgTemp.toBlob().height != null && imgTemp.toBlob().width != null) {


                IMGhight = imgTemp.toBlob().height;
                IMGwidth = imgTemp.toBlob().width;
                height = alturaImg;
                width = larguraImg;

                if (height > deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                    if (height > deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                        height = deviceHeight * hightFactor;
                        width = (((deviceHeight * hightFactor) / IMGhight) * IMGwidth);
                    }

                    if (width < deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                        width = deviceWidth * widthFactor;
                        height = (((deviceWidth * widthFactor) / IMGwidth) * IMGhight);
                    }
                } else if (width > deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                    if (width > deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                        width = deviceWidth * widthFactor;
                        height = (((deviceWidth * widthFactor) / IMGwidth) * IMGhight);
                    }

                    if (height < deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                        height = deviceHeight * hightFactor;
                        width = (((deviceHeight * hightFactor) / IMGhight) * IMGwidth);
                    }
                } else if (height < deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                    if (height < deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                        height = deviceHeight * hightFactor;
                        width = (((deviceHeight * hightFactor) / IMGhight) * IMGwidth);
                    }

                    if (width < deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                        height = deviceWidth * widthFactor;
                        height = (((deviceWidth * widthFactor) / IMGwidth) * IMGhight);
                    }
                } else if (width < deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                    if (width < deviceWidth * widthFactor) {
                        width = deviceWidth * widthFactor;
                        height = (((deviceWidth * widthFactor) / IMGwidth) * IMGhight);
                    }
                    if (hight < deviceHeight * hightFactor) {
                        hight = deviceHeight * hightFactor;
                        width = (((deviceHeight * hightFactor) / IMGhight) * IMGwidth);
                    }
                }

                var imagem = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    width : width,
                    height : hight,
                    image : img
                });

                viewObj.add(imagem);
                imagem = null;
                imgTemp = null;
                IMhight = null;
                IMGwidth = null;
                hight = null;
                width = null;
                img = null;
                hightFactor = null;
                widthFactor = null;
                viewObj = null;
                deviceWidth = null;
                deviceHeight = null;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'm already declare all variables to null for GC but I still get the memory problem. does some one now how to fix this?

[image: This is the layout that I need do make.]

the problem is that I need to reuse the same images for something else so I need them to bee beg.

Comment: altough you're resizing the image, it will weight exactly the same. So I think you'll have to find some kind of lazy loading solution for your app.

Comment: something around 30 images with a size of 1024*800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really resize the image and save it to a thumbnail file. And not just resize the imageview and display the whole image in it. That would save you some memory.

Also you are creating multiple blobs `imgTemp.toBlob()`. Run this command once and reuse the blob variable. The same for all the other calculations. It's not much but saves you some time/space when you just calculate it once and reuse the value.

But you need to resize the image, perhaps with a custom android module which allows batch resizing with a whole folder or array of files if thats something you need.

Comment: I receive images from a server and I get them from the URL. How is it the best method to create an image array? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extracting `imgTemp.toBlob()` to a common variable will have a drastic positive impact on your memory consumption. Taking a look at what happens under the covers, you're actually loading the image in to memory multiple times EVERY TIME YOU CALL `toBlob()`! I see 4 usages in your code plus the actual image view usage, times 30 images, you've got several hundred copies of your bitmaps being thrown around.

See the source code here for more proof --

In TiUIImageView.java:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/e6a5f6c086a019dbdf810e225bb13c5c8d9115ac/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/TiUIImageView.java#L945

And in TiBlob.java:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/415bd6c66dcc55b1a59a59574f3babd3c3a84ede/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/TiBlob.java

Answer (score 0):

If you receive images from server, then it's better to put resized images at server. The resolution of images at server can be the maximum width*height you would create an ImageView in your app.

Now, if you are going to use those images at some other screen in bigger ImageView (like to show image in fullscreen), then you can have different folders at server for both scenarios. e.g.

- for smaller ImageView, create a **thumbnail** folder at server
- for bigger ImageView, create another folder named as **pictures**.
- Now, suppose your actual image at server is **my_image.jpg** of size width = 1024, height = 800, then put thumbnail image of 300*234 keeping the aspect ratio same with this path ***thumbnail/my_image.jpg*** and actual image at this path ***pictures/my_image.jpg***

Again, if you really want to resize the images according to your requirements, then there are pretty neat methods in [Titanium Blob API like imageAsThumbnail](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsThumbnail)

Also, if you want to load 30 images of 1024*800 at once, then you will have to look into lazy-loading methods as nothing can save device's memory in case if you create 30 ImageViews of 1024*800 at once.

Finally, it would be better if you can hint us what kind of UI you want to design so that we can suggest you better ways to do it, not just resizing the images and performing many calculations on them.

Comment: I have updated my question. I reeded the titanium doc and there they say that lazy-loading  only works on IOS but i need it for android

Comment: You can implement your own ways for lazy-loading as there could be more than 1 way to do it. As I said that a simple mockup or wireframe design will be better for us to help you better how to do what you want.

Comment: I have put an image on my question of the UI that I need to create

Comment: If the GREY-SQUARES in front of labels like **Centro Culturul** are the ImageView you need to optimise for, then I better suggest you to decrease the resolution of your images at server....because there are two benefits of this process:    **1 -** You can fetch images much faster because of low size. (try to keep the size around 200x200 as I think it would be enough for those images in grey-squares.   **2 -** Your app will use quite sufficient low memory after scaling down the images.   **3 -** Following my answer of using thumbnail way, you can show the bigger images anytime.

Comment: Yes the grey squares are the image places. But I need the images beggar on an other screen. But I think I found the size that works for both situations. My images are now 700 px width and sorting around 400px hight  and it works

Comment: That's why I suggested you to use smaller images for grey-squares, and fetch bigger images based on the selected option.